# (Mithril) TypeError: m is not a function... 'm' is an instance of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mithril.js

I am a new FronT-end developer learning "Mithril JS". I created sample  page using MVC Pattern. The page is not working after console error in NavBar.js (see below):

```
TypeError: m is not a function. (In 'm("div", "Hello")', 'm' is an instance of Object)
```

I created the following files

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="app"></div>
     <script src="bin/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import m from "mithril";

const root = document.getElementById("app");
var NavBar = require("./views/NavBar");
m.mount(root, NavBar);
```

**/views/NavBar.js**

```
var m = require("mithril")

module.exports = {
    view: function() {
        return m("div", "Hello")
    }
}
```

I compiled everything with node.js.
I used the same syntax as the mithril [documentation](https://mithril.js.org/simple-application.html)

Suggestions????

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a problem with using two conflicting kinds of module resolution, [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (ESM) and [`require`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) (CJS).

Many Javascript build tools like Webpack have tried to make these two mechanisms appear equivalent, but the mechanisms are slightly different. I would recommend using only one in this case: `require`, and leaving out `import`.

Mithril's API was originally written to expose a single entity, `m`, which is both a function (`m('div')`) and an object (`m.request('url')`) with several methods and primitive properties. In the case of `require`, which simply exposes a Javascript value from one module to another, this is unambiguous. However `import` operates differently - one can import a single default entity, and / or any number of named entities. The easiest way to fudge this into an 'equivalent' `require` paradigm is to treat object properties as named exports and the single `m` function as a separate default import, but this doesn't align with the simple `require` mechanism whereby there is one single reference for an entity fulfilling all these aspects. TL; DR: `import` & `require` often try to appear semantically equivalent, but they're not, and mixing and matching can cause strange ambiguities.

Mithril has no official ESM support, so I'd recommend sticking with `require`.

Comment: Using only `require` does not solve the problem.
`const m = require('mithril').default` in NavBar.js solve the problem.
Tank you for your time!